# latex formulae editor for google slides that allows editing after the generation of the formula?

Tags: google-slides, latex

I have tried MathType, Hypathia Create, Equation Editor++ add-ons for Google Slides.
They all produce an image of the formula, but what if one needs to edit the formula? You need to retype it from scratch as far as I can see.

Is there an add-on that produced *editable* formulas in Google Slides? Would be awesome if it could be added also as part of regular text boxes.

Comment: Welcome to [Web Applications](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/ "https://webapps.stackexchange.com/").  Web application recommendation requests are [off-topic](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic#:~:text=Web%20application%20recommendation%20requests%2C%20Software%20Recommendations%20may%20be%20suited%20%2D%20please%20review%20their%20policies%20before%20posting) on this site.  The [Software Recommendations](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/) site may be better suited for this question.  Please review their policies before posting

Answer (score 1):

The [Auto-LaTeX Equations](https://workspace.google.com/marketplace/app/autolatex_equations/850293439076) Chrome extension seems to have a "de-render equation" button that might do the trick.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This indeed has a `de-render` functionality. Not tested yet on a large set of equations, but at least it fills the bill. Thanks